# How to properly use number_to_phone or similar way to style a phone number input

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form

I always like to mention that I'm fairly new to rails and building my first app. So I apologize in advance if the following question is too stupid.

I have a form with a `:office_number` that I would like to format. I'm running rails 4 with bootstrap 3. Here's my current code:

```
<%= f.input number_to_phone(:office_number, :groupings => [2, 4, 4], :delimiter => "-"), label: "Office #", :input_html => { class: "form-control" }, :label_html => { :class => 'form-label' } %>
```

I get no erros, but when I type the number, it doesn't get styled as it was supposed to. I want to achieve a number like this `48-1234-5679`. Better yet, if is not asking too much, I want the number to show exactly like this `(48) 1234-5678`. Any help on how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Check the [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/NumberHelper.html#method-i-number_to_phone). Maybe you need the `area_code` option.

GL & HF.

Comment: Even if I set number_to_phone(:office_number) it doesn't get styled. So I don't think the problem is with the area_code

Comment: Why not try a phone number form helper? http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#other-helpers-of-interest